# Flutter, when assign onpressed to 'null' cause TextButton or ElevatedButton to disappear instead of disable (grey)

Tags: flutter, dart

When I write

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Test')) //or
TextButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Hehe'))
```

in flutter 3.10.4 (Dart 3.0.3). The button becomes disappear instead of disable (grey), is that recent flutter update?

Is there another way to disable button?

Comment: Hvae you changed your theme data in the root widget?

Comment: Yes, I do have configured ThemeData ( colorScheme : ...) .

Comment: Could you please share it?

Comment: @Abdelkrim, I found it, it is in 'ThemeData( onSurface: Colors.white)' , Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, I answered just for the sake of marking the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

As was discussed in comment, the issue was setting

```
ThemeData( onSurface: Colors.white)
```